# AWS Detecting Elastic IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to know the elastic ip associatied with my ec2-instance.   When i remote via putty and type ifconfig it's doesn't display elastic ip and providing the internal ip.  Is there a unix command to get the elastic ip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the command line, type `ec2metadata` for ubuntu-based images. On the amazon-based images, I use `ec2-metadata` Your public ip will be among the other data displayed.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer http requests then regardless of OS:

```
http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4
```

Feel free to explore `http://169.254.169.254/` tree. Please note slash is required after some nodes in the tree despite it isn't visible in the answer from the upper level.

For example:

```
root@aw [~]# curl -w "\n" http://169.254.169.254/latest/
dynamic
meta-data
user-data
```

Row `dynamic` does not have slash at the end, but if you try as is you'll see nothing:

```
root@aw [~]# curl -w "\n" http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic
(empty line)
```

Then try with slash:

```
root@aw [~]# curl -w "\n" http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/
instance-identity/
```

Of course this 'website' works inside AWS only.